# Deal with formatted columns and search feature in smart-table

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Can someone help me search formatted columns? Using global search, in smart-table examples (and my code too), if i format some column (money filter for example), and the original value was 102, and i show $102.00 on columns, and user entry 102.00, the search feature does not find this value, cause original value is 102, not 102.00 (with dot and zeros), how can i deal with it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using an input textbox with st-search directive on to filter your numeric value column which you in markup format using an angular filter. Something like this?

```
<table st-table="collection">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input st-search="id" type="search"/></td>
        <td><input st-search="cost" type="search"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in collection">
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
        <td>{{row.cost | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is several ways to go about this:

- If the value is for display only, you may preformat it before putting it on the scope for consumption. This will also bring other benefits; when the numeric has decimals you will not have problems with rounding up on the second decimal place in the currency filter and searchable base value, the filter will not be evaluated each digest cycle which improves performance significantly for large and complex datasets and it requires no other change to your code than preformatting the property and removing the currency filter.
- You may choose to implement your own search directive where you may apply some logic to the value before passing it on to smart table (see the stNumberRange directive in plunker below for how to implement your own search plugin).
- Create your own filter where the comparison logic fixes your issue (see plunker and query object in directive together with customFilter)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Idbc1JNHKylHuX6mNwZ6?p=preview